# I want to use categories in Outlook the same way I use labels in Gmail. What's the best practice?

Tags: outlook, label, gmail, categories

I have been using Gmail labels for several years, and they are far superior to folders. You can add as many labels as you want, and when you archive an email, it is stored under that label. So I can open the label and see all emails tagged with it. It's better than folders, because sometimes there are multiple properties to an email.

I am using Outlook Professional 2016 (the Desktop version, not online). Outlook has folders, and has added categories, which act just like labels. But the mechanism is a little clunkier than Gmail. You have to do a search for a category, where in Gmail labels look like a folder and all labels are listed.

Bottom line, I find myself attaching a category AND putting the email in a folder, which seems like double work. What is the best practice, here? Should I just create an "Archive" folder, and put all emails with categories into that folder, and use search to look for categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a search folder: right click "Search Folders" node, select "New Search Folder...", Categorized Mail, select the category.

Comment: Thank you! The powers that be closed this question, but you gave me the answer. I appreciate it.